# Matplotlib Stopping an Animation

Tags: matplotlib

The following code is the function that's used to create an animation of appearing and then fading-away points on a Matplotlib basemap.  I was wondering how it's possible to slow the interval down between each point? In this case, I have set frames = 62, because there are 62 points.  However, changing the interval to a larger value doesn't seem to slow down the interval between points.  Am I missing something here?  The attached animation function and GIF is attached below.  The rest of the code isn't here, because I didn't think it was relevant to the question. Thanks.
[image]

```
def animate(frame):
        eq_num = frame % len(X)
        i = frame % len(P)

        P['colour'][:,3] = np.maximum(0, P['colour'][:,3] - 1.0/len(P))

        P['size'] += P['growth']

        magnitude = X['magnitude'][eq_num]
        P['epicentre'][i] = m(*X['epicentre'][eq_num])
        P['size'][i] = 5
        P['growth'][i]= np.exp(magnitude) * 0.1

        if magnitude < 4:
            P['colour'][i]    = 0,0,1,1
        else:
            P['colour'][i]    = 1,0,0,1
        scatter.set_edgecolors(P['colour'])
        scatter.set_facecolors(P['colour']*(1,1,1,0.25))
        scatter.set_sizes(P['size'])
        scatter.set_offsets(P['epicentre'])
        return scatter,

    ani = FuncAnimation(fig,animate,frames=62,interval=1000,blit=False)
    ani.save('animation.gif', writer='imagemagick', fps=100)
    #plt.show()
```

Comment: The time between subsequent calls to the animate function is determined by `interval`. For the saved gif it is determined by the fps parameter.

Comment: In addition to what @ImportanceOfBeingErnest said, if you want the points to grow several times before a new point appears, you will have to introduce a real time parameter. E.g. `t=frame*dt` and then you'll have a starting time (`tn`) for each epicenter that you compare to your current `t` to decide whether the point should be shown or not.